# Cannot insert into table with identity column from linked server

Tags: sql-server, insert, linked-server, identity-column

I have the following table:

```
  use db_name;
  create table dbo.tbl_name(
  id_col int identity(1,1),
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(50)
  );
```

into which I can insert values without issue:

```
insert into dbo.tbl_name
select
col1,
col2
from dbo.other_tbl_name;
```

The issue arises when I attempt to insert into the table from a linked server:

```
insert into [server_name].db_name.dbo.tbl_name
select
col1,
col2
from dbo.other_tbl_name;
```

This gives the following error message:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
> definition

If I try to set `identity_insert` on so I can include the identity column in the insert I get the error message:

> Cannot find the object
> "server_name.db_name.dbo.tbl_name" because
> it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

which is somewhat misleading, given that I can select from the table and even issue `update` statements. I guess I don't have permission to set `identity_insert` on from the linked server, though I can do it on the server itself directly with the same credentials.

So how can I insert into this table from the linked server?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should first consult the documentation when you run into problems. `set identity_insert` does not support 4-part names. And you should always specify the column list for an insert statement - a best practice. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly define the columns in your INSERT statement:

```
insert into [server_name].db_name.dbo.tbl_name (col1,col2)
select
col1,
col2
from dbo.other_tbl_name;
```

Comment: That was it! I knew explicitly listing columns is always considered best practice, but I thought I had already observed this standard because of the column list in the select statement. I was used to the syntax in the post, and since it has always worked when on a single server I never looked up this different syntax. 

Thanks a hundred!